# Base Adapter in Asynctask not working

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-asynctask

I am working with facebook app for my project and I'm getting a json from the graph API. I have a custom listView with hashMap, but when I run, the list wont populate but there isn't any errors. please help me.

**here are the codes:**

```
public class PageFeedHome extends Fragment {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> feedList;
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private String feedMessage;
ListView listView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_home_activity,
            container, false);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_lv);
    feedList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadPosts().execute();

    BaseAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), feedList,
    R.layout.feed_item_view, new String[] { TAG_MESSAGE, TAG_NAME,
    TAG_ID }, new int[] { R.id.message, R.id.author,
    R.id.id_tv });

     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return view;
}

private class LoadPosts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true,
                new Session.StatusCallback() {

                    // callback when session changes state
                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                            Exception exception) {
                        if (session.isOpened()) {

                            new Request(session, "/163340583656/feed",
                                    null, HttpMethod.GET,
                                    new Request.Callback() {
                                        public void onCompleted(
                                                Response response) {
                                            /* handle the result */
                                            Log.i("PostFeedResponse", response.toString());
                                            try {
                                                GraphObject graphObj = response
                                                        .getGraphObject();
                                                JSONObject json = graphObj
                                                        .getInnerJSONObject();
                                                JSONArray jArray = json
                                                        .getJSONArray("data");
                                                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                                    JSONObject currObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                                    final String feedId = currObj.getString("id");
                                                    if (currObj.has("message")) {
                                                        feedMessage = currObj.getString("message");
                                                    } else if (currObj.has("story")) {
                                                        feedMessage = currObj.getString("story");
                                                    } else {
                                                        feedMessage = "Posted a something";
                                                    }
                                                    JSONObject fromObj = currObj.getJSONObject("from");
                                                    String from = fromObj.getString("name");

                                                    HashMap<String, String> feed = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                                    feed.put(TAG_ID, feedId);
                                                    feed.put(TAG_MESSAGE, feedMessage);
                                                    feed.put(TAG_NAME, from);

                                                    feedList.add(feed);
                                                }
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }).executeAsync();

                        }
                    }
                });

        return null;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: `Async` inside `Async` is wrong . Call `notifyDataSetChange` in `onPostExecute`

Comment: Add the content in Base Adapter onPostExecute method.

Comment: thanks for the response, i got the answer the the guy below. have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this code :

```
BaseAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), feedList,
R.layout.feed_item_view, new String[] { TAG_MESSAGE, TAG_NAME,
TAG_ID }, new int[] { R.id.message, R.id.author,
R.id.id_tv }); //initialize adapter

 listView.setAdapter(adapter); //set adapter
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To the `AsyncTask's` `onPostExecute` to make sure the `feedList` is already inserted from the `onBackground`.

Or if you prefer to initialize your `adapter` and setting the adapter to the `listview` in the onCreate, just move `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to the `onPostExecute`. This is recommended if you call the `AsyncTask` multiple times, because theres **no** need to initialize and set the adapter multiple times. (see my comment in the code)

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> feedList;
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private String feedMessage;
ListView listView;
BaseAdapter adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_home_activity,
        container, false);

listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_lv);
feedList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
BaseAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), feedList,
R.layout.feed_item_view, new String[] { TAG_MESSAGE, TAG_NAME,
TAG_ID }, new int[] { R.id.message, R.id.author,
R.id.id_tv });

 listView.setAdapter(adapter);

 new LoadPosts().execute();




 return view;
 }

  private class LoadPosts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true,
            new Session.StatusCallback() {

                // callback when session changes state
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {
                    if (session.isOpened()) {

                        new Request(session, "/163340583656/feed",
                                null, HttpMethod.GET,
                                new Request.Callback() {
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            Response response) {
                                        /* handle the result */
                                        Log.i("PostFeedResponse", response.toString());
                                        try {
                                            GraphObject graphObj = response
                                                    .getGraphObject();
                                            JSONObject json = graphObj
                                                    .getInnerJSONObject();
                                            JSONArray jArray = json
                                                    .getJSONArray("data");
                                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                                JSONObject currObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                                final String feedId = currObj.getString("id");
                                                if (currObj.has("message")) {
                                                    feedMessage = currObj.getString("message");
                                                } else if (currObj.has("story")) {
                                                    feedMessage = currObj.getString("story");
                                                } else {
                                                    feedMessage = "Posted a something";
                                                }
                                                JSONObject fromObj = currObj.getJSONObject("from");
                                                String from = fromObj.getString("name");

                                                HashMap<String, String> feed = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                                feed.put(TAG_ID, feedId);
                                                feed.put(TAG_MESSAGE, feedMessage);
                                                feed.put(TAG_NAME, from);

                                                feedList.add(feed);
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).executeAsync();

                    }
                }
            });

     return null;

   }
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+feedList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

  }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the response, it seems that i got the answer from the guy above. have a nice day!

Comment: i have some enemy he is doing that work but no need this i have knowledge so i can create new account